# Do interactions in mixed designs inflate the main effect of fixed factor?

Tags: interaction, mixed-model

Explain in clear way why in a mixed design the presence of an interaction between a random and a fixed factor inflates the estimate of the main effect of the fixed factor.

Comment: The peremptory tone of this question suggests it is [tag:homework].  What steps have you taken towards an answer?  Could you be more specific about where you need guidance?

Comment: I have read the textbook that the question was derived from (Maxwell and Delaney), as well as several other stats books, the lecture notes, and googled for over an hour trying to find the answer.Just need a point in the right direction...or an explanation of why it inflates the main effect.